# Lagrange Multiplier functions Gradients direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

when the contour of one function is tangible to the contour of another function. I know contour and gradient are orthogonal to each other.  Shouldn't be the gradient(del g- pink) of the g(x,y) be opposite side(i.e., 180) to the gradient(del f - light blue) of f(x,y)??

Kindly do correct me if I am wrong.

[image: Gradient directions of Lagrange Multipliers]

Comment: 5:00 of what? please present the question in mathjax

Comment: the Lagrange's multiplier works if the two sets were disjoint.

Comment: The gradients can be parallel or anti-parallel, depending on the problem and even between points within the same problem. They are parallel if increasing the value of the constraint a little would increase the value of the objective function at the new critical point. The other way if it would decrease.